# PHP - Get File/Folder Relative Path

Tags: php, directory, path, relative-path

With JavaScript, if you have the input tag set up like this...

```
<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory directory />
```

You able to get the relative path of a selected file by doing this...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].files[0].webkitRelativePath
```

My question is how do you get the relative path of a file from a input tag just like this with PHP? With PHP your able to get a file name, type, size but how do you get its relative path?

Answer (score 0):

**Relative** directories don't work the way you think they should in `PHP` (according to your JavaScript way of thinking)
 -- Mainly because `PHP` is **server side** and theoreticaly can access any file within the operating system (unless jailed etc) -- The closest you're going to find is something like   `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which will give you the relative path to the **web root** -- However if you are running `PHP` client based -- There is no "relative root" --  In `cli`, you simply use `./` (or nothing), `../`, `/`  to tell php "**related to** the same directory as the script"  IE

```
./directory/yourfile.txt   //This starts in the SAME directory as the php file

../directory/yourfile.txt  // This goes up one directory, and then you can drill back down.

../../../directory/directory/directory/file.txt  // Just like above, but up 3 directories

/directory.file.txt // Starts from the server root -- IE /var/www/etc/etc/etc
```

Other than using these methods you can *write your own* way of handling this with your own methods etc --  There are many schools of though on this as well.  Some say using **absolute** paths is the way to go ... But others argue that for portability **relative** is the way.  Really it depends on your program and what you're using it for .. Whether it's getting deployed etc ..  If it's the latter, and it's web-based, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will suffice, but you should structure your program to make classes, controllers, modules etc etc easily accessible when coding. (hence write methods to handle directory locations)

---

**UPDATE per your comment**

You asked if it was possible to pass this to php, and the answer is - yes, and no.

Yes, if the page has already loaded and you want to send the info as part of an action (form submit / AJAX call)

Yes, if you already have loaded the page, and have stored a cookie with this information on a previous page / session

No if a user has never been to the page and first pageload has already happened, and no other actions are expected to happen such as AJAX or form submissions.

Based on what you're asking you should be able to simply:

```
var mypath = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].files[0].webkitRelativePath

 $.post("send_path_to_php.php", {path: mypath}, function(result){
     alert(result);  // result of php page response
 });
```

This will send the `var` **mypath** to a `php` file called `send_path_to_php.php`. The `php` file will be able to extract `$_POST['path]`  Then you do whatever you want in said `php` --    Whatever you `echo`/`return` will be in the callback of `result`

Comment: It is not possible to get the relative path of a file using the input tag from a clients computer?

Answer (score 0):

Relative path to a file stored on your computer is not available for PHP as it's Server Side. So once you submit your form your file is included into the request and the source path is not available anymore.

But you could potentially use different techniques (a combination of JavaScript making async request to the server - AJAX, or another field, could be hidden, storing the file path info) to pass the path information to the server.